# Convert NxM numpy array to (N*M)x1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I have a numpy array that looks something like this:

```
            day1, day2, ..., dayM
year month
1            .                    
2                .
.                    .
.                        .
.                            .
N                               (yearN,dayM)
```

To me this format looks sort of weird. I would rather have the data in one column for this sort of work and later on load into pandas (or I could start by loading into pandas if there is something available that is more convenient).

Is there a few simple methods I can use to do this specifically for the "day" rows and columns? I'm not very concerned with keeping the "year" and "month" so let's pretend they're not there.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that although each row in the "day" matrix is 31 in length I only need to retain the number of corresponding to that month (leap years included). Looks like it might be time for a loop...

Comment: have you tried the [reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) function of numpy?

Comment: Should be pretty direct with pandas `stack` and some string parsing.

Comment: @U2EF1 I've never used stack before but actually it looks really useful. Might take a little bit of messing around with the index afterwords though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reshape suggestion ended up being what worked the best. This is what ended up working for me and was much faster than I though

```
reshaped = np.reshape(X,N*M)
result = np.delete(reshaped, np.where(reshaped==32744))
```

Where X is the matrix mentioned above.
The `np.delete` is to get rid of the filler values in the matrix for the ends of months with less than 31 days.